# Could not find or load the main class.

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to run this code and Eclipse said that

> could not find or load the main class.

I tried to modify the public class Ejemplo adding `public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception` but it did not work. I am really new in Java and I do not know how to solve this problem.

```
package rs232;
import giovynet.serial.Baud;
import giovynet.serial.Com;
import giovynet.serial.Parameters;
import java.awt.Frame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Ejemplo extends Frame {

    // Variables y objetos visuales
     JLabel Etiqueta=new JLabel();
     JTextField Texto=new JTextField();
     JButton Boton=new JButton();

     JLabel Etiqueta1=new JLabel();
     JLabel Etiqueta2=new JLabel();
     JButton Boton1=new JButton();
     String caracter = "";

     public Ejemplo()
     {
    // Frame
     setVisible(true);
     setLayout(null);
     setTitle("Lectura y escritura de datos");
     setSize(325,125);
    // Etiqueta
     Etiqueta.setBounds(20,50, 100, 20);
     Etiqueta.setText("Enviar un digito");
     add(Etiqueta);
    // Caja de texto
     Texto.setBounds(120,50,15, 20);
     add(Texto);
    // Boton
     Boton.setBounds(150,50,100, 20);
     Boton.setText("Enviar");
     add(Boton);
    // Etiqueta 1
     Etiqueta1.setBounds(20,80, 100, 20);
     Etiqueta1.setText("Leer un digito");
     add(Etiqueta1);
    // Etiqueta2
     Etiqueta2.setBounds(120,80,15, 20);
     add(Etiqueta2);
    // Boto 1
     Boton1.setBounds(190,80,100, 20);
     Boton1.setText("Leer"); 
     add(Boton1);
    // Evento boton1
     Boton.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {

    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {

     Parameters configuracion = null;
     try {
    // //Definición de parametros
     configuracion = new Parameters();
    // //definición del puerto que se va a utilizar
     configuracion.setPort("COM2");
    // //definición de la velocidad de impresión, se debe tener en
    // cuenta dicho argumento en las especificacion de velocidad del dispositivo
     configuracion.setBaudRate(Baud._9600);
    // asignamos los parametros al objeto com1
     Com com1 = null;
     com1 = new Com(configuracion);
    // envio de un de caracter
     com1.sendSingleData(Texto.getText());
    // fin de envio de secuencias de escape ESC/POS
     com1.close();
     } catch (Exception e1) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e1.printStackTrace();
     }
     }
     }
     );
     //Evento boton 1
     Boton1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
     public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
     System.out.println("mouseClicked()"); // TODO Auto-generated Event stub mouseClicked()
     Parameters configuracion = null;
     try {
     configuracion = new Parameters();
     configuracion.setPort("COM1");
     configuracion.setBaudRate(Baud._19200);
     Com com1 = null;
     com1 = new Com(configuracion);
     while(caracter.equals("")){

     caracter =com1.receiveSingleString();
     System.out.println(caracter);
     Etiqueta2.setText(caracter);

     }
     com1.close();
     caracter ="";
     } catch (Exception e1) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e1.printStackTrace();
     }
     }
     });
     }
    }
```

Note: this is an example of how to read and write a single character to a serial port

Comment: Can you run anything at all on Eclipse, let's say a `Hello World` example? And can you provide more info on the error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create a main class.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  new Ejemplo();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to Ejemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   new Ejemplo();
}
```

..and tell Eclipse "Ejemplo" is the main class.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by other answer, add the `main` function as:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  new Ejemplo();
}
```

After that, right click on the class, go to `Run As` -> choose `Java Application`